# Confusing blog post "Does ES6 make JavaScript frameworks obsolete?"

Tags: discussion, blog

I read a really confusing blog post "[Does ES6 make JavaScript frameworks obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/10/does-es6-make-javascript-frameworks-obsolete/?cb=1)" announced at StackOverflow. It reads as if the article was written six years ago. All of the comments are suggesting that, too?

Can someone shed some light on this blog post? Was it posted accidentally? If not, is this the quality of blog posts you want to announce at your start page?

Comment: "*is this the quality of blog posts you want to announce at your start page?*" from my limited experience with the blog, the quality isn't that high. This article in particular is terrible but I don't tend to read the blog because even then the bar doesn't seem to be very high.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that by the Google and SO's search. :-(

Comment: It's not on SO, so SO's search would not show it to you. It is on Meta, so you would need to search Meta. Given how recent it is, even searching for "blog post" would find it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=blog%20post

Comment: I searched for the blog post title. It's always the right search terms...

Comment: "f not, is this the quality of blog posts you want to announce at your start page" - quality simply has nothing to do with it. Ask yourself this: why should you even listen to what bloggers on SO have to say versus the thousands of other people you can find elsewhere on the web? They're one and the same, only the site the blog is posted on is different.

Comment: @Gimby presumably SO has higher standards than the thousands of other people you can find elsewhere on the web. Well, at least it's a somewhat reasonably assumption to make if you've not read the blog. If anything, this article cements that there is indeed no difference.